# Hash-like Functions

Tags: hash, string-hashing

Are there any cryptographically secure hash functions that can be given a array of strings to hash, and will always calculate the same output no matter what order the array elements are in?

I realize that one could merge the array elements into one string and hash that, but I'm asking specifically about functions that are order-independent (like bloom filters) but cryptographically secure (unlike bloom filters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking the same question on the Cryptography StackExchange, I was referred to this question which described Multiset Hash Functions, specifically the MSet-Mu-Hash and MSet-VAdd-Hash functions: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/54544/how-to-to-calculate-the-hash-of-an-unordered-set

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array, apply whatever your favorite encoding is to convert the array into one string, and apply a standard cryptographic hash.

Comment: I'm asking about the theoretical existence of such a function for a case where multiple individuals cannot sort a set, or do not know how it should be sorted.

Comment: Mathematically, aren't we talking about imposing *some* sort of order in any case, otherwise the hash function won't output the same result?

Comment: Well that's why I'm asking if such a thing exists. The closest parallel I can think of is a bloom filter, but those are far from cryptographically secure.